# Can't get a succesful jira create issue api response

Tags: node.js, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I am trying to call jira rest api POST /rest/api/3/issue from a node js application. I am getting the following error  even though am passing correct details. I am passing issueType as 10103 and remaining sensitive params as required. Here is my
**nodejs code.**

```
app.post("/webhook", function(req,res,next){

    console.log(req.body);
    let options = {
       method: 'POST',
       url: req.body.tags["jira:endpointURL"]+"/rest/api/3/issue",
       auth: {
         user: req.body.tags["jira:user"],
         password: req.body.tags["jira:token"]
       },
       headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
       },
       
       json: {
          "update": {},
          "fields": {
            //"summary": req.body["subject"],
            "summary": "Test",
            "description": {
              "type": "doc",
              "version": 1,
              "content": [
                {
                  "type": "paragraph",
                  "content": [
                    {
                      "text": "body",
                      "type": "text"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            "issuetype": {
              "id": req.body.tags["jira:issueType"]
            },
            "project": {
              "key": req.body.tags["jira:project"]
            }
          }
        }
    };

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);
        console.log(
              'Response: ' + response.statusCode + ' ' + response.statusMessage
        );
        console.log(body);
        res.send("OK");
    });
});
```

**Error thrown**

- summary: "Field 'summary' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown.",
- description: "Field 'description' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the fields to the screens first.

See:

- https://support.atlassian.com/jira-cloud-administration/docs/add-a-custom-field-to-a-screen/
- https://support.atlassian.com/jira-cloud-administration/docs/configure-issue-screens/#Configure-a-screen--x27-s-tabs-and-fields